# How many IE6 users are real users?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, user-agent

I'm supporting an existing website and IE6 suppport seems to come up given the amount of rich AJAX and other technology sprinkled into the solution.  IE6 is definitely going the way of the dinosaur, however the people who operate the site insist that 20% of Internet users are still rolling with IE6.

My question is this: how many of the 20% are real domestic US IE6 users?  A great number of these people hitting with IE6 strike me as being out of country running illegal installs of Windows XP ineligible for Windows Update.  I say this because I've travelled the world quite a bit and used cafes all around where this is the case.  Do anyone have any real hard numbers for recent domestic US IE6 numbers?

Regards.

Comment: None! They're all robots if still on IE6 :)

Comment: As I sit here trying to make background-image pngs transparent in IE6... :)

Comment: First, does it matter for your website whether or not they come from illegal Windows XP installs? If they are part of your website's audience, shouldn't they be serviced?  Why would they visit your website, if they're not "real users" of it? Second, why don't you look at the statistics available to you? You know the exact IP addresses that visit the site. Do a reverse DNS lookup to determine where they're from. It doesn't matter how many IE6 users exist in the rest of the world. The only relevant metric in your case is how many IE6 users exist *on your site*.

Comment: Some corporates still use specific versions IE6 because of internal software compatibility issues. Some Adjust their proxys to make IE6 look like IE7 for external web access, os there may be more IE6 in use than you realise!

Comment: Why can't you look this up for your specific website? You could log traffic and check by user agent or something like that. Either way, that would be more accurate than relying on numbers from websites that may be vastly different from yours.

Comment: The problem isn't the site itself, as it's targeting a US-only audience due to the information it presents being of no value to someone out of country.

Comment: @Nissan Fan: That's irrelevant. Different websites will have different browser demographics, even within a single country. That's like asking about the national African-American population because you're starting a local business in Texas--the population there will differ from the national average, probably considerably, and therefore the national numbers are useless to you. Your website might have a lot of IE6 users, or it might have very few; the only way you can find out for sure is to log the requests and check.

Comment: Total confirmation bias.  Look at the logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At [last count on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp), IE6 users made up slightly less than 10% of the global web population. (As the commenters rightly point out, these statistics are based on visitors to a web development site, so you can expect it to be somewhat biased, although the numbers for IE6 here are very similar to the other sites.)

[In the US](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-US-monthly-200902-201003), IE6 users make up about 6% of the traffic.

[Here is one more site](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) that tracks browser usage across thirty thousand or so sites. IE6 is currently used by slightly less than 10% of internet users on these sites.

Comment: That's for visitors to the W3 which are likely to be more technically current than average users

Comment: Unfortunately, I wouldn't rely on w3schools for counting browser shares -- the users accessing w3schools are likely to be considerably different from most users on the web. In particular, I suspect IE6's share to be significantly greater than 10%.

Comment: @Steerpike: No, it's for visitors of the deceptively-named "w3schools.com", which is wholly unrelated to the W3 organization.

Comment: @Anonymous, it's still people who are going to be into learning HTML/CSS/javascript.

Answer (score 6):

You're forgetting locked-in corporate users and people with old systems. If you don't care about those users, either (foreign users *are real users*), you can safely ignore them, I guess.

Comment: I worked at a large Government organisation (With more than 20,000 desktops) and IE6 was part of the SOE. Not only that, all other browsers were prohibited.

Answer (score 4):

Numbers using IE6 are going to depend heavily on your specific site. it's certainly possible for IE6 usage to be very low but for your specific site to have a high percentage of users on IE6.

General browser stats can be found [here](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-200902-201003) but it's much more important to get figures on your own specific sites under your control when making any kind of browser support decisions.

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, I have some Government customers that by IT policy are prohibited from upgrading past IE6 on their workstation "because IE7 is too insecure."

I sh*t you not.

Comment: I feel for you mate. Luckily the Government environment I work in actually listened when I said we need to kill off IE6. We didn't move to Firefox (which I only suggested half-jokingly - as I knew this would be pushing my luck) but when I suggested it and stated my reasons why - everyone had IE7 the next day. Unheard of isn't it?

Comment: You must work for a better Government than I do. In our case there is an outside contractor that supports the network for an entire (large) agency and dictates things like this. My actual users aren't far enough up the food chain to effect any change. Many have resorted to bringing their personal machines to work to get around problems like this.

Comment: Update: I just got a call this week to confirm that our web app works in IE7, apparently in 2013 they are ready to move forward (just not all the way).

Answer (score 1):

If by "real" users you mean actual humans and not bots and scripts I don't have any hard and fast figures, but I would suggest that the proportion of "bots" or "non-real" users to "real" users is probably going to be similar across the spectrum of popular browsers and therefore something that you can totally discount when looking at your proportion of IE6 users.

If by "real" you mean "people who have actually paid for Windows XP and up"; honestly, unless you're Microsoft or are very concerned about the morals of software piracy, I wouldn't factor it into my decision of whether or not to drop support for IE6.

Myself, I cannot wait until the day I can drop support for IE6. I'm not going to totally drop support though - just let a few things slide and some functionality drop off gracefully. At the moment I'm sitting around 10% - after taking a massive drop in the last 6 months. Once I hit 5% (which I'm estimating will be around the end of the year) I'm going to start rolling down support. Which is great news because that's around the time we're doing the website redesign.